# Making a function call onclick whenever I touch

Tags: javascript, ios, jquery-mobile

I use `joystick.js`. My aim is for whenever I touch (`ontouchstart`) it will call `onclick`.

I tried this below but it didn't work. My joystick is preventing me from touch buttons. I even replaced `onclick` with `ontouchstart` but I use jQuery. I can't change all. For any idea I would be grateful.

```
document.getElementById("overlyas").ontouchstart = function(e){         
   var ontouchstart = onclick;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As a work around for ios not recognising the onclick event you can in your main css file set the cursor to pointer:

```
* {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

then it will register onclick events. I think it only recognises onmousedown by default.

Not sure if this actually answers your question but it saved me a lot of trouble with writing hybrid apps....

Comment: It didn't work, but thanks anyways its 2-3 days I am trying, I can't figure out I think because I Jquery not sure though.